# Perl: How to get the 'use VERSION' number

Tags: perl, version

Is there a special variable or a function which gives me the number of `use VERSION` (in this case `5.12.0`) when running the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
```

Comment: What would you do with that information? (just curious)

Comment: adding to a `--info` option output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just quickly checked `feature.pm` code - the version itself is not stored anywhere. Alex's answer already showed how to test particular features that results from the call.

Also note that `use VERSION` can be called on several places (in modules for instance).

One hypothetical option would be to override `use` and record the version number somewhere for inspection.

**Edit:** Some poking in the hook direction:

```
use version; # for version parsing
use subs 'require';
BEGIN {
    sub require {
        warn "use ",version->parse($_[0]);
        # ... emulate original require
    };
}

use 5.12.0;
```

This limited example reports the version specified, but for real use it would have to be much more robust.

Comment: Gee, I do not think it possible to override "use" (and a quick test does indeed point in that direction) Even if it where, I'd feel inclined to advise very much against it.

Comment: @AlienLifeForm - added simple experiment in this direction.

Answer (score 4):

You can, during compile time, poke about in the hints variable (`${^H}`) (where dragons lurk) and look into the hints hash (%{^H}) (where dragons lurk, but in a public documented sort of way), this will let you know which specific features are enabled.  I don't know how to work out if specifically a feature bundle, or all given features, were requested:

```
perl -le "use feature qw(:5.12); BEGIN{print $^H;print foreach keys %^H}"
133376
feature_unicode
feature_say
feature_state
feature_switch

perl -le "use 5.12.0; BEGIN{print $^H;print foreach keys %^H}"
134914
feature_unicode
feature_say
feature_state
feature_switch
```

Comment: I suppose someone thinks it doesn't answer the question. It's not the answer per se. I'll give you a thumbs ups.

Answer (score -2):

Either one of these gives you the version of the interpreter:

> **$]**
> The version + patchlevel / 1000 of the Perl interpreter.  This variable can be used to determine whether the Perl interpreter executing a script is in the right range of versions.  (Mnemonic: Is this version of perl in the right bracket?)
>
> **$PERL_VERSION**
> **$^V**
> The revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter, represented as a "version" object.
> This variable first appeared in perl 5.6.0; earlier versions of perl will see an undefined value. Before perl 5.10.0 $^V was represented as a v-string.

Those will be > than what you have on the "use" line: if you need that exact string, bite the bullet and stick it in a variable as in:

```
 use 5.12.0; $WANTPERL='5.12.0';
```

Comment: `$]` is deprecated as of v5.6. Also, it isn't the question to acquire the *current* version, but the *expected* version of Perl.

Comment: if $] is deprecated, then I would expect The Fine Documentation -  perldoc perlvar, use warnings  - would say so (and it does not as of v5.12.4). But if you know better, than you should submit a documentation patch - though I suspect that you are confusing $] with $[, which is in fact deprecated. And yes, I understood the question, and gave what I deem an acceptable answer according to my understanding and knowledge of the subject. I see you differ - that's your privilege.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html - scroll all the way down and look for *Deprecated in Perl 5.6.*

Comment: The link you quote is from 5.14, so it appears the docs are now fixed. 

I have no idea what the "randomly pick blah" means, if you have other
complaints taking them to emails would be great, not to mention appropriate. And, I do not come here to "go far". That may be what some other folks do - do you have news about their maturity? 

Cheers.